# A question about the word 'blood' meaning 'a close relative'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

In an article about a family in Queens, New York, a young man, seventeen years old, who had lost both his father and mother to Coronavirus, and, together with his sister, had contracted the disease yet recovered, stated :

> “Because it’s just me and my sister [left], we sort of have to rely on each other," he said. “We were the only blood left.”

[MSN News - 22nd September 2020](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/news/us/unfathomable-us-death-toll-from-coronavirus-hits-200000/ar-BB19jlxY?li=BBoPWjQ&ocid=mailsignout)

I had not come across the word 'blood' used in this way, but then I am a Brit.

Does it mean, simply, a close relative ?

Is this an American English expression ?

---

EDIT : I have a vague recollection of hearing someone address someone else as 'blood' but that may be a false memory triggered by association.

P.S. I know my header title is a little ungrammatical but the system did not allow me to put a full stop. I had to add a question mark, for reasons that I fully understand.

Comment: I think it's just the shortened version of *blood relatives*.

Comment: @NigelJ Is the speaker from a particular demographic? I'm British and it seems strange to me, too.

Comment: @Greybeard The young man lives in Queens, New York.

Comment: It doesn't sound strange to me, as BrE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The only blood left" refers to the remaining members of a family.

The same use of blood occurs in *bloodline* = "all the members of a family group of people or animals over a period of time, especially when considering their shared family characteristics".

[Cambridge Dictionary online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bloodline)

It relates to genetic connection rather than to marriage, so a long bloodline is a line of genetic connection going back through parents, grandparents, great grandparents ... Having "royal blood" is a genetic connection to royalty.

Comment: The question is not about the word "bloodline", but about "blood" on its own to refer to a blood relative or to blood relatives collectively.

Comment: @RosieF Yes indeed, but what is your point? The answer refers to "blood" first in the context of family and then by showing its use and connotations in "bloodline". I suggest that the two are easily distinguishable and that a discussion of "bloodline" helps make clear the meaning of "blood".

Answer (score 10):

Apparently an AmE expression:

***[blood relative](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blood%20relative)*** (US)

> someone who has the same parents or ancestors as another person

> - Your sister is your blood relative, but your brother-in-law is not.

(Merriam-Webster)

This connotation of [blood](https://www.etymonline.com/word/blood) is actually quite old:

> Meanings "person of one's family, race, kindred; offspring, one who inherits the blood of another" are late 14c.

(Etymonline)

Comment: Can you edit this and give any justifications why you think this phrase applies to the original request? Simply copy-pasting the definition of the phrase does not answer the question.

Comment: I know what the OP is asking about, but simply copy-pasting the definition of the phrase seems to be a LMGTFY answer. You can add quotes from other sources and of course add your *own* commentary.

Comment: This isn't specific to AmE - it exists in [British English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blood-relation?q=blood+relative) too.

Comment: @psmears - yes, curiously M-W defines it as a US expression. I think that as a metaphor it is common in many languages.

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer which doesn't need any changes.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blood+relative%2Cblood+relation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3 Seems that "blood relation" was more common in British English, then in the 2000s American movies, publications, novels, magazines etc. began to saturate (or infiltrate) the British market, and now "blood relative" has the upper hand.

Comment: It's that "relative(s)" vs "relation(s)" thing, I think I posted something about it.... ah, yes here it is [Is there any difference between “a few relatives” and “a few relations”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134653/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes, for some reason “blood relative” has been common in AmE apart from the last couple of decades where it is apparently used also in BrE. Strange is it? After all England has a longer tradition of royal blood than the USA